# Sorting array by insertion sort

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I'm trying to sort an array using Insertion Sort.
Instead of changing and rearranging elements of array itself, I'm using another array named rank to Map to point to original array.
here is my code

```
int i,j;
int ar[] = {50,14,51,25,10};
int rank[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
for(i=1 ; i< 5 ; ++i)  // second element onwards
{
    int temp = rank[i];  // stores current value in temp variable      

    /**
     * temp = 1
     * j = 0 
     */
    j = rank[i] - 1;
    while ( ar[temp] < ar[ rank[j] ] && j > -1)
    {
        rank[j+1] = rank[j];      // move elemnts in map forward
        j--;
    } // end loop

    // insert temp at proper place
    rank[j+1] = temp;    

}

for(i=0 ; i< 5 ; ++i)
    printf("Rank : %d, Number : %d \n",rank[i],ar[i]);
```

But, it's not giving an expected output. Can anyone point towards what is the mistake in the logic ?

Comment: You're going to have to narrow it down further than simply "It doesn't work". Get a simple test case, use a debugger and track the code's execution. Chances are, this will help you find the solution. If not, it will at least narrow it down to a specific section of code.

Comment: `j = rank[i] - 1;`.  Are you trying to decrement the value in element `i` or access the element right before `i`?

Comment: i used netbeans debugger. what i found out is j is going to -2 instead of stopping at -1. so i added an extra constraint j > -1 in while loop.now when j = -1 then condition inside while loop should return false terminating it. but it's returning true and i have no idea why.

Comment: you are moving elements in rank but keep comparing elements in AR (which never move)... that might be your problem

Comment: @nightshade i didn't got you. what condition should i be putting in while loop then ? could you write it programmatically please

Comment: Does rank value 0 mean the smallest or the largest?

Comment: 0 means the smallest. i.e. if rank array is {1,2,0,5,4} for eg then in original array third element should be the smallest .

Comment: @BrainDead You problem is that you may not get into the while loop even if ar[temp] is smaller than some values in the sorted portion of rank[]. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic flaw is as following:
At this code section

```
   while ( ar[temp] < ar[ rank[j] ] && j > -1)
    {
        rank[j+1] = rank[j];      // move elemnts in map forward
        j--;
    } // end loop
```

`rank[j]` means the rank of the value at `ar[j]`.

And when you use `ar[rank[j]]`, you are comparing `ar[temp]` to the value indexed at `"the rank of the value at ar[ j ]"`,  which means you are not comparing to the biggest value in the sorted portion of `rank[]`.

Therefore, you may not get into this loop even if `ar[temp]` is the second smallest

For example:

So far during loop#2 `(i = 2)`

> ar[] : {50,14,51,25,10};
>
> rank[] : {1,0,2,3,4}; ({1,0} is the sorted portion of rank[])

The `0` only means `14` is the smallest value in `{50,14}` (the scanned portion of `ar[]`)
AND `ar[rank[2]]` ( `ar[0]`) only happens to be the largest value in `{50,14}` (the scanned portion of `ar[]`) by coincidence

If this value (`ar[rank[2]]`) is not the largest, and happens to be smaller than `ar[temp]`, you program will just skip the loop. Even if `ar[temp]` is smaller than all the other values in `ar[]`

Answer (score 0):

```
rank[j+1] = rank[j]
```

makes no sense. You should swap them.

Answer (score 0):

This was the code I had when took data structures class...

In the while condition it checks V... and inside the loop it moves the elements in V...

In your code you are comparing in one array and moving in the other... if you need the original position of elements you could just copy the array into a new one and sort the new array, instead of creating those ranks... (If you really need those ranks I'm pretty sure you could create while you sort)

[image]

Comment: How about adding this in a code section instead of an image? Maybe translate it too ...